# display randomly selected images to class

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `box2` with `<img />` inside it.

I have used a random image selection function for selecting random images,

I want to display the randomly selected image **one by one** to the image src of class `box2`.

How do I achieve it?

I use

```js
function rvalue() {

  var array = [];
  var tempimages = [];


  var ArrayOfImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg', '11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg', '14.jpg', '15.jpg', '16.jpg', '17.jpg', '18.jpg', '19.jpg', '20.jpg'];

  arrayLength = ArrayOfImages.length;

  for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    array[i] = ArrayOfImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];

  }

  console.log(tempimages);
}
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  background-color: #ff9900 2px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue">
  <div class="box" id="2">
    <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:100px; height:100px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: why not shuffle ArrayOfImages and display from 0 to end?

Comment: how ? im a newbie can you explain

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: how to display in img src after shuffling from an array?

Comment: change src of img, `document.querySelector("#slide").src = //new img path` should work

Comment: new img path should be what?

Comment: the path of the image you want to display?

Comment: I don't know enough about your application to know if this is truly helpful, however, consider loading all your images into the page and possibly hiding and showing them randomly rather than loading as it will help with loading performance possibly.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: on loading all images and hiding images and showing?